# Protobuf format implementation

Tags: clickhouse

I’m trying to understand implementation of protobuf support in ClickHouse in more details. Looking at the source files https://clickhouse.com/codebrowser/ClickHouse/src/Formats/index.html I’ve got the impression that messages received from Kafka are manually parsed on the basis of the .proto file and fields are converted into clickhouse format.

The .proto format is rich and it’s hard to understand the way proto types are converted to clickhouse types from just looking at clickhouse sources.

Is there some kind of specification to clarify the mapping between proto and clickhouse types and the way this conversion is implemented?